# Google AI Platform: Error Code 400: Response size too large

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-earth-engine, google-ai-platform

I'm going to do predictions on Google Earth Engine using a deep learning model hosted on Google AI platform. The problem is that when I apply the model on the images, I get the following error in Google Earth Engine:

> Error: AI Platform prediction service responded with error code 400:
> 'Response size too large. Received at least 3574386 bytes; max is
> 2000000.'. (Error code: 3)

The model has only three layers (an MLP), and the image is not big either. How can I address this issue?

Comment: Can you share a working code snippet of your prediction request? Are you predicting using AI Platform library or the Earth Engine library?